# Injective linear operator as an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Suppose $S \in \mathcal{L}(\textsf{V})$ and $S$ is injective. Define $$\langle u,v\rangle_1 = \langle Su,Sv\rangle$$ Show that $\langle u,v\rangle_1$ is an inner product on $\textsf{V}$. The proof that I came across feels circular. Here I just focus on the property $ \langle u+v,w\rangle_1 = \langle u,w\rangle_1+\langle v,w\rangle_1$ :

$$\begin{matrix} 
\langle u+v,w\rangle_1=\langle S(u+v),Sw\rangle & & & (1) \\
\langle S(u+v),Sw\rangle=\langle Su+Sv,Sw\rangle & & & (2) \\
\langle Su+Sv,Sw\rangle=\langle Su,Sw\rangle + \langle Sv,Sw\rangle & & & (3) \\
\langle Su,Sw\rangle + \langle Sv,Sw\rangle=\langle u,w\rangle _1+ \langle v,w\rangle_1 & & & (4)
\end{matrix}$$

But doesn't line $(3)$ use the very fact that we are trying to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it seems that you already assume that $(V,\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ is an inner product space. Otherwise the question doesn‘t make sense.

Put differently: You already know that $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is an inner product (which you use in line 3); and you want to show that $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_1$ also is an inner product on $V$.

Comment: I see. The problem does not state that V is an inner product space though.

Comment: @pmac that‘s pretty sloppy :D

Comment: Ohhh, no. That comment triggered a memory. I'm the sloppy one. Here, earlier on in the chapter: 'For the rest of this chapter, V denotes an inner product space over F. Facepalm.
'

Comment: @pmac I guess we figured this out then 

Comment: By the way, you are fifteen?!? Wow, good for you, I wish I knew this kind of math when I was your age.

Comment: @pmac Thanks for the nice message 